# createContextualFragment is just spitting back the html from the string in string form

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I apologize, this should be simple.  I just have a string containing html that I want to append to el as "real html" and return for display.

My code, taken from other stackoverflow answers:

```
let fragmentFromString = function (strHTML) {
  return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
}
let x = fragmentFromString(decodeURI("<span><B>Test</B> this</span>"));
el.appendChild(x);
```

BUT, all it does is append the text including the html as a child on el.  It doesn't actually create the nodes and make "Test" bold, etc...

What I see in my browser is all of:

> <span><B>Test<>/B> this</span>

What I WANT to see in my browser is all of:

> **Test** this

What simple thing am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use 'decodeURI' ? Just delete that.

Comment: Wait.  Solved. my string was html encoded.  It needed $("<textarea/>").html(value).text();  Thank you Poul Bak

Comment: I would like to mark this answered by Poul Bak, but see no way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you use `'decodeURI'` which is wrong in this case, since it's not an encoded URI.
Simply delete it, and it should work.

You should use a html string in your function.